# JSON table schema to bigquery.TableSchema for BigQuerySink

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a non-trivial table schema (involving nested and repeated fields) defined in JSON format (with the name, type, mode attributes) and stored in a file. It has been successfully used to populate a bigquery table with bq load command.

But when I try to do the same thing with Dataflow Python SDK and BigQuerySink, the `schema` argument needs to be either a comma-separated list of `'name':'type'` elements, or a `bigquery.TableSchema` object.

Is there any convenient way of getting my JSON schema to a `bigquery.TableSchema`, or do I have to transform it to a `name:value` list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently *you cannot directly specify a JSON schema*. You have to specify the schema either as a string that contains a comma separated list of fields or a `bigquery.TableSchema` object.

If the schema is complex and contains nested and/or repeated fields, we recommend building a `bigquery.TableSchema` object.

Here is an example `bigquery.TableSchema` object with nested and repeated fields.

```
from apitools.clients import bigquery

table_schema = bigquery.TableSchema()

# ‘string’ field
field_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
field_schema.name = 'fullName'
field_schema.type = 'string'
field_schema.mode = 'required'
table_schema.fields.append(field_schema)

# ‘integer’ field
field_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
field_schema.name = 'age'
field_schema.type = 'integer'
field_schema.mode = 'nullable'
table_schema.fields.append(field_schema)

# nested field
field_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
field_schema.name = 'phoneNumber'
field_schema.type = 'record'
field_schema.mode = 'nullable'

area_code = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
area_code.name = 'areaCode'
area_code.type = 'integer'
area_code.mode = 'nullable'
field_schema.fields.append(area_code)

number = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
number.name = 'number'
number.type = 'integer'
number.mode = 'nullable'
field_schema.fields.append(number)
table_schema.fields.append(field_schema)

# repeated field
field_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
field_schema.name = 'children'
field_schema.type = 'string'
field_schema.mode = 'repeated'
table_schema.fields.append(field_schema)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that the Python SDK is alpha, so I will direct further issues to [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK) until it has matured a bit.

Answer (score 10):

The above snippet posted by Andrea Pierleoni works with older versions of the `google-cloud-bigquery` python client, for example for version `0.25.0` of `google-cloud-bigquery` that happens to install via `pip install apache-beam[gcp]`.

However, the BigQuery Python client API has changed drastically in more recent versions of `google-cloud-bigquery`, for example in version `1.8.0` that I am currently on, `bigquery.TableFieldSchema()` and `bigquery.TableSchema()` don't work.

If you're on a more recent version of the `google-cloud-bigquery` package, here's how you can get the required `SchemaField` list (required to create the table, for example) from a JSON file. This is an adaptation of the code posted above by Andrea Pierleoni (thanks for that!)

```
def _get_field_schema(field):
    name = field['name']
    field_type = field.get('type', 'STRING')
    mode = field.get('mode', 'NULLABLE')
    fields = field.get('fields', [])

    if fields:
        subschema = []
        for f in fields:
            fields_res = _get_field_schema(f)
            subschema.append(fields_res)
    else:
        subschema = []

    field_schema = bigquery.SchemaField(name=name, 
        field_type=field_type,
        mode=mode,
        fields=subschema
    )
    return field_schema


def parse_bq_json_schema(schema_filename):
    schema = []
    with open(schema_filename, 'r') as infile:
        jsonschema = json.load(infile)

    for field in jsonschema:
        schema.append(_get_field_schema(field))

    return schema
```

Now, suppose you had a table's [schema already defined in JSON](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specifying_a_json_schema_file). Say you had [this particular "schema.json" file](https://gist.github.com/nonbeing/9e1cbec94a4ad7a17cf3948db5ccb901), then using the above helper methods, you could get the required `SchemaField` representation for the Python client like so:

```
>>> res_schema = parse_bq_json_schema("schema.json")

>>> print(res_schema)

[SchemaField(u'event_id', u'INTEGER', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'event_name', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'event_types', u'STRING', u'REPEATED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'product_code', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'product_sub_code', u'STRING', u'REPEATED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'source', u'RECORD', u'REQUIRED', None, (SchemaField(u'internal', u'RECORD', u'NULLABLE', None, (SchemaField(u'name', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'timestamp', u'TIMESTAMP', u'REQUIRED', None, ()))), SchemaField(u'external', u'RECORD', u'NULLABLE', None, (SchemaField(u'name', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'timestamp', u'TIMESTAMP', u'REQUIRED', None, ()))))), SchemaField(u'timestamp', u'TIMESTAMP', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'user_key', u'RECORD', u'REQUIRED', None, (SchemaField(u'device_id', u'STRING', u'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField(u'cookie_id', u'STRING', u'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField(u'profile_id', u'STRING', u'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField(u'best_id', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ()))), SchemaField(u'message_id', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'message_type', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'tracking_id', u'STRING', u'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField(u'funnel_stage', u'STRING', u'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField(u'location', u'RECORD', u'NULLABLE', None, (SchemaField(u'latitude', u'FLOAT', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'longitude', u'FLOAT', u'REQUIRED', None, ()), SchemaField(u'geo_region_id', u'INTEGER', u'NULLABLE', None, ()))), SchemaField(u'campaign_id', u'STRING', u'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField(u'topic', u'STRING', u'REQUIRED', None, ())]
```

Now to [create a table having the above schema using the Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#bigquery-create-table-python), you would do:

```
dataset_ref = bqclient.dataset('YOUR_DATASET')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('YOUR_TABLE')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=res_schema)
```

You could optionally set time-based partitioning (if needed) like this:

```
table.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
    type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
    field='timestamp'  # name of column to use for partitioning
)
```

And this finally creates the table:

```
table = bqclient.create_table(table)

print('Created table {}, partitioned on column {}'.format(
    table.table_id, table.time_partitioning.field))
```

Comment: This kind of sample should be in google documentation or source code. Thank you both.

Comment: Beautiful answer! very thorough..

Answer (score 7):

There is a build-in transformer function in the BigQuery library:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
...
client = bigquery.Client()
client.schema_from_json('path/to/schema.json`)
```

Comment: This answer should really be promoted to the top.  While all of the previous answers are correct in some way, they are all outdated and this one method from client object replaces them.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case I already had some json loaded in bigquery with a schema automatically generated.

So I was able to get the autogenerated schemawith the command:

```
bq show --format prettyjson my-gcp-project:my-bq-table |jq .schema > my-bq-table.json
```

the schema can then be transformed into a `bigquery.TableSchema` with this snippet

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery


def _get_field_schema(**kwargs):
    field_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
    field_schema.name = kwargs['name']
    field_schema.type = kwargs.get('type', 'STRING')
    field_schema.mode = kwargs.get('mode', 'NULLABLE')
    fields = kwargs.get('fields')
    if fields:
        for field in fields:
            field_schema.fields.append(_get_field_schema(**field))
    return field_schema


def _inject_fields(fields, table_schema):
    for field in fields:
        table_schema.fields.append(_get_field_schema(**field))


def parse_bq_json_schema(schema):
    table_schema = bigquery.TableSchema()
    _inject_fields(schema['fields'], table_schema)
    return table_schema
```

It will work with the bigquery json schema specification and if you are lazy like me you can avoid to specify `type` and `mode` if you are happy with a field that is a nullable string by default.

Comment: Thanks man! And if you need the schema to create the table in the BIgQuery UI (for example, partitioned tables must be created by hand) don't forget to select the `fields` key in the `schema` field, that is: `bq show --format prettyjson my-gcp-project:my-bq-table | jq '.schema.fields' > my-bq-table.json`

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you can use the built-in [parse_table_schema_from_json](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools.parse_table_schema_from_json) function:

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json

with open('schema.json') as f:
    schema_string = f.read()
table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(schema_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program that can help you.

```
import json
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery


def bq_schema(json_schema):
    table_schema = bigquery.TableSchema()
    with open(json_schema) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for p in data:
            field = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
            field.name = p['name']
            field.type = p['type']
            field.mode = p['mode']
            table_schema.fields.append(field)
    return table_schema
```